# "null" function name decoded from ethereum transaction, which function I executed on earth

Tags: etherscan

### question

hi, I got a [ethereum tx](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x13389268ed1cae395a94cc111528ef8e5b929221af4ecc2a0c7e977dd7dbc38d) decode like this

[image]

I don't know why there's a function named "null", I look at smart contract, no function name is "null".

so I am confused, which function I have executed?

### tx & contract detail

transaction : https://etherscan.io/tx/0x13389268ed1cae395a94cc111528ef8e5b929221af4ecc2a0c7e977dd7dbc38d

smart contract: https://etherscan.io/address/0x3e66b66fd1d0b02fda6c811da9e0547970db2f21#code

Comment: What tool did you use? Neither Etherscan nor [EthTx.info](https://ethtx.info/mainnet/0x13389268ed1cae395a94cc111528ef8e5b929221af4ecc2a0c7e977dd7dbc38d) show that function. Perhaps the tool had a temporary glitch.

Comment: @Ismael I use etherscan.io , I just checked, it's still null. you can open this link https://etherscan.io/tx/0x13389268ed1cae395a94cc111528ef8e5b929221af4ecc2a0c7e977dd7dbc38d -> Click to see more -> Decode input data

Comment: It appears to be a bug, perhaps related to ABIEncoderV2 usage in the contract.

Answer (score 1):

It's a decoding error. The method ID from the transaction data is `0xe2b39746`
[image]

so the method being called in the balancer contract is `multihopBatchSwapExactIn`

```
keccak256("multihopBatchSwapExactIn((address,address,address,uint256,uint256,uint256)[][],address,address,uint256,uint256)")
// e2b397460e82d32113ac4547ec4bc4743832545a243c51c515cfa34f27512812
```

The source shows the decoding library is [ethereum-input-data-decoder](https://github.com/miguelmota/ethereum-input-data-decoder) which currently is buggy with ABIEncoderV2.

[image]